# Why is inbuilt flash delay in manual mode nikon d5200?

Tags: nikon, flash

i have nikon d5200. In manual mode whenever i click a photo with flash, flash fires after 1sec. But it works fine in auto mode, there is no delay. can someone tell me why this delay is ?

Comment: You have made a statement. What are you asking? Also, what shutter speed is selected? Do you have second curtain sync enabled? If you have a shutter speed of around one second with second curtain sync enable then this is perfectly normal behavior.

Comment: @MichaelClark even if i shoot at 1/200 flash fires after some delay

Comment: What exposure mode are you using? What lens? What metering mode? What AF mode? What ISO? What other relevant settings are enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it is a shutter delay, not a flash delay. The flash cannot fire one second after the shutter closes, but the flash does have to wait on the shutter to open.

You have at least four ways to cause a shutter delay.

D5200 menu D5 has a one second shutter Exposure Delay.

Selftimer is a shutter delay.

Redeye Reduction is about one second shutter delay while the flash fires about three times first.  This is in the sync menu (like with Rear Curtain sync delay).

The ML-L3 remote menu has a shutter delay mode.

You should get the free D5200 Reference Manual, at
http://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13948/~/nikon-product-manuals-available-for-download

It has much more of this stuff in it than the "User Manual", and the PDF file is searchable.